# npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EINVAL: invalid argument, fchown

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I got the following error when running `npm ci` in my docker container

```
$ npm ci
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EINVAL: invalid argument, fchown
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EINVAL: invalid argument, fchown
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EINVAL: invalid argument, fchown
```

My configuration

```
node:18.15-alpine
npm: 9.6.2
```

Has anyone had the same error and found a way to fix it?

*I did found [this related topic](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5998) but wasn't that helpful*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fixed my problem

```yaml
  before_script:
    - npm i -g npm@latest --force
  script:
    - npm ci --force
```

1. Forcing my docker to download the latest npm version
2. Forcing npm ci